# Css in umbraco cms

Tags: .net, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm building page on umbraco cms. And I've in css property background-image. The question is, how add url to this property, when image is in Media section?

Answer (score 3):

You can place all of the css in your stylesheet except the image url.
Then in your page, you put a `style="background-image: url('...');"` into the tag where you want to apply this image.

*Example:*

**In your stylesheet you have a class like `.image`:**

```
.image {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-repeat: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

**In your .cshtml page you have:**

```
if (Model.Content.HasValue("image")) // image is the document property alias of the media picker
{
    // Get the media object using the id value of the image property
    var mediaItem = Umbraco.Media(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("image"));

    // Get the src of the image
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('@mediaItem.GetPropertyValue("umbracoFile")');">
      ...
    </div>
}
```

**Another more short solution could be:**

```
<div class="image" style="background-image: url('@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.Image).Url');">
    ...
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to add design images, just create a new folder `images` directly in your umbraco folder structure. Then add these images in your CSS like you used to do:

`url('../images/medimas.png')`

Comment: I know, but how add url of image to this property?

Comment: View update, if your image is in a document property using the media picker

Comment: Just like that: background-image: url('@Umbraco.Field("frontLogo")') ?

Comment: View my answer, you first need to get the media object using your property and then get the src value

Comment: view update, if its design images you don't need the media section, just add your images in a folder called `images`. Then you can add it directly in your css stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

It should be this assuming that there is a media id in the "image" property.  If you are using a media picker then as long as you have selected a media item then this will work. The mediaItem variable contains a media item which now has media properties like Url for example that can be used.

```
if (Model.Content.HasValue("image"))
    {       
        var mediaItem = Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("image"));
        <section id="intro" class="intro" style="opacity: 0.7; background-image: url('@mediaItem.Url');">
            <div class="slogan">

            </div>  
        </section>
    }
```